# How to get call log history of a windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am new to windows phone development.Can anyone explain me how to display call log details of a windows phone.I am using SDK 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no API in the SDK (7 or 8) to retrieve Call History. 
It's mainly for protecting the user and privacy concerns.